# In Java, what is the difference between new TestA() and TestA obj = new TestA()?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

```
interface TestA { 
    String toString(); 
}
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new TestA() { 
            public String toString(){ 
                return "test"; 
            } 
        });
    }
}
```

In java, You can never instantiate an interface in java. But why the above code prints "test" as output instead of raising an error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are having an interface, normally you would be having a class which will implement that interface like this.

```
   class TestAImp implements TestA {

    //Some other Code

    String toString(){
      return "test";
    }

}
```

And to use this object you will be doing something like this

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new TestAImp().toString());
    }
}
```

Now suppose for some purpose you decide not to declare a class which implements that interface, but you want to implement that interface. This is where **anonymous classes** come into picture. In the case of anonymous class you don't write the code of that class in some file .java but instead write the code of that class while creating the object itself.

Since your interface has only one method, you can create anonymous classes, like this. I am declaring 2 classes Test and Test2 which have 2 different implementations of the interface.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new TestA() { 
            public String toString(){ 
                return "test1"; 
            } 
        });
    }
}

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new TestA() { 
            public String toString(){ 
                return "test2"; 
            } 
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect..!! Thank you :)

Comment: Glad that you understood..:)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not instantiating an `interface` but defining (and instantiating at the same time) a new `class`, so a new type, which implements `TestA` but it has no name.

That's an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Comment: If I say ClassName obj = new ClassName() then it is class/interface instantiation and when I say new ClassName() ; it does not instantiate the class. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If my Class "Demo1" has a constructor Demo1(), will this constructor gets called if I use "new Demo1();" statement instead of Demo1 d = new Demo1(); ?

Comment: @TechGuy The new question you're asking is totally unrelated to the original one.  If you still need an answer, please consider asking a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is not between the notations you have in your title. The difference is that you are creating an anonymous class that implements the interface. That is completely legal. The notation may look a bit strange but when you get used to it you will have no problems with it.

Comment: If my Class "Demo1" has a constructor Demo1(), will this constructor gets called if I use "new Demo1();" statement instead of Demo1 d = new Demo1(); ?

Comment: @TechGuy JVM doesn't care if you store the instance somewhere or not. It behaves exactly the same every time you create an object.

Comment: @TechGuy The new question you're asking is totally unrelated to the original one. If you still need an answer, please consider asking a new question.

Answer (score 0):

This is an anonymous class definition based on the TestA interface

Comment: If my Class "Demo1" has a constructor Demo1(), will this constructor gets called if I use "new Demo1();" statement instead of Demo1 d = new Demo1(); ?

Comment: @TechGuy The new question you're asking is totally ... crimeney, why did you ask it three times?  Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You created an anonymous class for it. The object created of this anonymous class will be implementing `Test`. And it will be passed to `println(...)` function.
Which will later call `toString()` method of the passed object and print returned value on screen. And that's why it prints "test";